# Reference file from elsewhere and web front paths

Tags: typescript, frontend, es6-modules

I'm trying to move to es6 modules for the front.
At work, I'm on a website based on PHP & Symfony for the back with the following simplified structure:

```
src
    ClientSpecificBundle
        Resources
            private
                typescript
                    tsconfig.json
                    main.ts
            public
                js
                    main.js
    CompanyGenericBundle
        Resources
            private
                typescript
                    tsconfig.json
                    foo.ts
            public
                js
                    foo.js
web
    bundles
        client-specific
        company-generic
```

Everything in `web` is exposed publicly and directly in HTTP.
`web/bundles/client-specific` is a symlink to `src/ClientSpecificBundle/Resources/public`.
`web/bundles/company-generic` is a symlink to `src/CompanyGenericBundle/Resources/public`.

What I'm trying to make work at first just so I can go on with everything else

**foo.ts**

```
function foo(): void
{
    console.log("Hello, World!");
}

export { foo };
```

**main.ts**

```
import { foo } from "/bundles/company-generic/js/foo.js";

foo();
```

I assume it's related to the tsconfig.json file properties baseUrl, path, reference, and/or composite.

I haven't been able to figure out yet how to use these to make it work.

How can I tell TypeScript that the modules should be loaded with a path that doesn't match the file system structure ?

```
src/ClientSpecificBundle/Resources/public/js/ -> /bundles/client-specific/js/
src/CompanyGenericBundle/Resources/public/js/ -> /bundles/company-generic/js/
```

Also, how can I tell TypeScript in ClientSpecificBundle that the module `/bundles/company-generic/js/foo.js` exists and is defined in `src/CompanyGenericBundle/Resources/public/typescript/foo.ts` so my file works ?